# Javascript: How to get values of an array at certain index positions

Tags: javascript, arrays, find

I have an array of values

```
arr = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

and I have another array of indexes

```
indexes = [0,2]
```

What is the best way to get the values of the array at these indexes ?

If I apply the method to the values above

it should return

```
["a","c"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
arr = ["a","b","c","d"]

indexes = [0,2]

const res = indexes.map(e => arr[e])

console.log(res)
```